# I cannot include OpenGL in Clion

Tags: c, visual-studio, opengl, ide, clion

fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
#include <GL/glut.h>

My directories and files in Clion:

[image]

Comment: Are you copying glut header and libraries into your source tree? I don't think that is the way it is supposed to be done. Keep them outside the tree, preferably where their setup program intended them to be, and set the `-I` and `-L` flags to appropriate values.

Comment: First of all, GLUT is not OpenGL. It is a completely outdated helper library on top of OpenGL and the various OS-specific OpenGL bindings. Second `#include <dir/file>` will only look in the system include paths, while `#include "dir/file"` will use the project's include paths (which typically include the directory where the source fuile is located).